# Blanks to be replaced as NA while extracting unique values from a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Below is the part of list i am working on, Property_Type is the header as well as the name of the list

```
Property Type
    Office
    Warehouse
    Mixed
    Terminal
    Office 
    Office

    Office
    Office
    Warehouse
    Warehouse

    Warehouse

    Warehouse
    Warehouse
    Warehouse
```

The Desired output is :-

```
Office
Warehouse
Mixed
Terminal
Blank
```

Comment: Could you please add some (dummy)data to your question showing which shows what data you are working with, your desired result and your current effort? It's hard to picture the descibed situation without visualization.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? And out of curiosity, why don't you use "Remove Duplicates"?

Comment: This is actually a part of a big worksheet having lot of formulas working, This list of unique values would be used as a drop down list for some other sheet, which should contain "Blank" as a value if there is any blank cell in the original list from which we are extracting this unique list of values

Comment: Pertinent information such as what you have just put in a comment should be added to the original question - people don't need to spend time checking all the comments to "build" your question...

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad,

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "Remove Duplicates" (Data tab : Remove Duplicates) then you get the output EXCEPT for two things:

1) Blank does not appear in the output - that's expected

2) "Office" appears twice -
     as I copied your data from your question and one office entry has a trailing space - excel assumes this is different data. This means you should control the data perhaps use TRIM().

Comment: Yes, i have used Trim in my formula that ii had posted originally here, but this list of unique values will be used as a drop down list for some other sheet which should contain Blank as an option in drop down, this would be possible only when we can have "BLANK" as a unique value for all the empty cells in the original list

Comment: Well, I can be sure that one of the "Office"entries you supplied had an extra space at the end...

Comment: @r_sh_07, if your list isn't dynamic I don't see why you wouldn't use the suggested method and just add "BLANK" to your list.